# warning when trying to plot regression surface

Tags: r

working with a data set called seg portion of it display below

```
       n   position  age   vehicle
1      0 0.61095890   29      1989
2      0 0.66301370   30      1989
3      1 0.99452055   42      1994
4      0 0.87397260   43      1994
5      0 0.04383562   44      1994
6      0 0.07397260   44      1994

gam1= gam(n~s(age)+ s(vehicle) + offset(log(position)),data=seg,family=Poisson)
ag<-seq(min(age),max(age),len=10)
veh<-seq(min(vehicle),max(vehicle),len=10)
data<-expand.grid(age=ag,vehicle=veh)
fit.gam1<-matrix(predict(gam1,data),10,10)
persp(ag,veh,fit.gam1,theta=45,phi=30,ticktype='detailed',xlab='age',ylab='vehicle',
zlab='n',expand=2/3,shade=.5)
```

I got this message

```
Error in model.frame.default(ff, data = newdata, na.action = na.act) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'age')
In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In predict.gam(gam1, data) :
     not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
  2: 'newdata' had 100 rows but variable(s) found have 39075 rows
```

Please what am I not doing right?

Thanks

Comment: I think your `data` needs a `position` variable. You have `age` and `vehicle` in there, but you haven't given a `position`.

Comment: Please I don't understand, how do I go about that?

Comment: Try creating a very small subset of your data and making sure your formulas and function arguments look **exactly** like the ones in the examples on the help page.   If that doesn't work, you will have to check your data's class (numeric, factor, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that the error was thrown at the time of the `predict` call. I'm thinking it might be safer to create a 'log_pos' variable and then pass that dataframe to gam before doing the `predict`. Then you wouldn't be in the position of needing to determine whether Simon Wood put in the interpretive machinery to do a full formula interpretation. Given that you already have the model fit, you could quickly find out by running:

```
data<-expand.grid(age=ag,vehicle=veh, position=0.7)
fit.gam1<-matrix(predict(gam1,data),10,10)
```

Also:

> 1) your example is too small to support a test.
>
> 2) you are using attach (and not admitting the nature of your sin.)

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly by my example being too small you are referring to my data set. Anyway that was just the first few observation from over 2000 observations. Tried suggestion but got same message.

Comment: You did not understand correctly. I was implying that until you posted a larger example that no further work was possible.